# Bind sending socket

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I have a form with two buttons, first is started to Listen socket, and show message boxes with address, from which address message was sended. The second button is for send message to address that i listening when i'm pressing listen button.  I'm trying to bind sended socket. For example, i wanna send it from port 50000. I'm using `Bind` method, but it's only working at first time, than exception become, that address usually can using only one time, and i need to reopen my form again. How can i solve this problem ? Here is my code for sending:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string local_host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
        string local_ip_address = Dns.GetHostByName(local_host).AddressList[0].ToString();
        IPEndPoint send_point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(local_ip_address), 50000);

        Socket send_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint connected_point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBoxIPListen.Text), 
                                                    Convert.ToInt32(textBoxPortListen.Text));
        try
        {
            send_socket.Bind(send_point);
            send_socket.Connect(connected_point);
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("TestTest");
            send_socket.Send(data);
            send_socket.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling send_socket.Close() in the Try part I would rather call it in a finally block to make sure that even if an exception is raised then you close the socket. Otherwise you may keep you socket open if anything goes wrong.

```
    try
    {
        send_socket.Bind(send_point);
        send_socket.Connect(connected_point);
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("TestTest");
        send_socket.Send(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        send_socket.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for advise! You right, better close it anyway. But unfortunatelly i anyway can send my message only first time, than exception becomes anyway :/

Answer (score 1):

`Bind()` is used in combination with `Listen()` to bind `socket` on to specified connections. Basically you can `Bind()` socket to listen only on specific port and address but to connect to another remote, you should use simple `Connect()` method.

As it was said in documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.bind(v=vs.110).aspx

> You must call Bind before you can call the Listen method. You do not need to call Bind before using the Connect method unless you need to use a specific local endpoint.

What does it means in your case? It means that you're trying to bind packets from ( assume ) 127.0.0.1:5000 to come through 127.0.0.1:4990. You can of course do that but you have to remember to unbind this socket from local endpoint whenever you want to "re-bind".

If this was your intended behavior then I can suggest `Dispose()` socket after closing it. This will unbind local end point from socket. Example:

```
send_socket.Close();
using ( send_socket ){ }
```

**EDIT:**

If it works only the first time I would recommend `using` the socket :

```
    try
    {
        using(send_socket) {
            send_socket.Bind(send_point);
            send_socket.Connect(connected_point);
            byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("TestTest");
            send_socket.Send(data);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Or you can keep your socket instance bound making a member field `Socket send_socket` as a member of your `Form` class with `send_socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket,SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);` option set.

Comment: Dziekuje! But the problem is that boss wanted that i send message from specified address. If i'm using just connect method, it's perfectly sending, but system choose port automatically, and this is not what my boss want :/ When i'm using bind before connect, it's works, i can use my own address, but it works only first time, and than become exception.

Comment: I tried using `(send_socket)`, but unfortunatelly it didn't help :/ Still have the same exception.
I will try second advise. So the full code will be like:
`try
            {

                    send_socket.Bind(send_point);
                    send_socket.Connect(connected_point);
                    byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("TestTest");
                    send_socket.Send(data);
}`

Comment: Strange, but second advise didn't help as well. I tried to put this anywhere at try, but didn't working.